# EXTENSION_BASE_URL causing 404 on some fonts

Tags: heroku, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 on Heroku and keep getting 404 errors for some fonts.  This just started happening earlier today but I haven't changed any of my code in several days.

This is a sample of what I'm seeing from laravel's error handler:

```
404 - https://www.example.com/%7B%7BEXTENSION_BASE_URL%7D%7D/b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf
404 - https://www.example.com/%7B%7BEXTENSION_BASE_URL%7D%7D/fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff
404 - https://www.example.com/%7B%7BEXTENSION_BASE_URL%7D%7D/af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2
```

I searched my entire directory for `EXTENSION_BASE_URL` and it doesn't exist anywhere in my code.

The user id's associated with these errors are not unique and it seems to be happening to multiple people. It's the same three font files as above each time.

My best guess is there's some kind of plugin people have installed that's trying to use a custom font that doesn't exist.  I can't find any reference to `EXTENSION_BASE_URL` when I do searches online, so I can't figure out where it's actually coming from.

The only custom fonts I use are an import for Raleway from the Google Fonts API.  I have jQuery 2.2.4, Bootstrap 3.3.7 and FontAwesome 5.4.1 which might also be including fonts with their CSS.  Aside from the Raleway include, the versions for the other CSS files haven't changed in a while.

Since it doesn't seem to be affecting everyone and I can't track down what these font files are, my plan is to simply exclude these font files from showing up in my logs.  I'd love to know what caused this though so I can take any other action if necessary

Comment: Hey there! I don't have much help to offer, but just wanted to say that I'm seeing the same error on a website I manage. My guess is the same as yours: it's a browser extension that's buggy.

Comment: Same problem here that started on June 30th 2021. It's either a buggy extension, or a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

We had this same problem with some of our users and we tracked it down to a browser extension called ProWriting Aid Grammar Checker which is for the website https://prowritingaid.com/.

In our case, not only was it creating the errors you mention with fonts, it also caused some JavaScript to execute improperly.

This extension is available on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge. We had users across all these browsers have the same problem.  It is clear that the problem code is shared across all these browser extensions' code base.

Having users uninstall that extension solved our issues.